# android custom dialog background

Tags: android, android-dialog

I need to show a custom dialog in my Android application. Standard `AlertDialog` design is unacceptable. Android docs say:

> Tip: If you want a custom dialog, you can instead display an Activity
>   as a dialog instead of using the Dialog APIs. Simply create an
>   activity and set its theme to Theme.Holo.Dialog in the 
>   manifest element:
>
> That's it. The activity now displays in a dialog window instead of
>   fullscreen.

Sounded promising. I did it, but transparency does not work! Background is always grey:

[image]

Here is a desc in the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyDialogActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar" >
</activity>
```

Here is a root of my activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    // Content ... //

</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried also `android:background="@null"` - effect was the same.
If I use `android:background="#ff0000"` then it's red (as it should be). But how do I make it transparent?

**Update**

I ended up with

```
<style name="MyThemeDialogCustom" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar" >
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

make theme like this

```
<style name="ThemeDialogCustom">
<item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for an idea. You solution "as is" threw an exception so I just inherited my theme from `android:Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar`. I updated my question to show the solution.

Answer (score 6):

Try...

You can avoid the gray background like this, Here I did get transparent background.

```
    ........
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_layout);
    Button dialogBtn= (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn);

    dialogBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //task
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
    .......
```

Answer (score 2):

```
dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
```

Comment: I love this answer. Is there something like a Dialog theme attribute to cancel this dim behind?

Answer (score 1):

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

Comment: Perhaps consider adding a little more context to your answer. An explanation is much more helpful than just code.

Answer (score 0):

i have used this as a style:

```
<style name="DialogTransparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateUnspecified|adjustPan</item>

    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
<!-- <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item> -->
```

it has also background transparent, setting the brackgroundDimEnabled parameter to false works for not showing the gray background that shows with the dialog in his back.