# Keep AlertDialog default layout params using custom window background

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

I need a dialog with custom background color and rounded corners. How can I keep default layout params using custom window background for AlertDialog?

Currently, my dialog has smaller left-right margin than in regular dialog. Also, dialog buttons such as positive and neutral have more shift from the edge of dialog.

```
<style name="DialogStuffTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_custom</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

bg_custom.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:angle="270"
                android:startColor="@color/Cyan200"
                android:endColor="@color/Green200"
                android:type="linear" />
            <corners
                android:radius="@dimen/dialog_corner_radius" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Check your <SDK_INTALL_DIRECTORY>/sdk/platforms/{Android API VERSION}/data/res/layout/alert_dialog_material.xml for default Alert Dialog layout. You can tweak it according to your requirement.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13669450/android-custom-dialog-background

Answer (score 1):

Should use this when creating AlertDialog: `new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyDialog)`

```
<style name="DialogBarButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_bar_enabled_selector</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogBase" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">@dimen/dialog_min_width_major</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">@dimen/dialog_min_width_minor</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/Animation.AppCompat.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:buttonBarButtonStyle">@style/DialogBarButton</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDialog" parent="DialogBase">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_custom</item>
</style>
```

values/dimens.xml:

```
<dimen name="dialog_min_width_major">65%</dimen>
<dimen name="dialog_min_width_minor">85%</dimen>
```

color/button_bar_enabled_selector.xml:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/colorAccent" android:state_enabled="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/TextDisabled"/>

</selector>
```

I don't know why color of dialog bar buttons had changed in this case. To fix this issue I have to use selector with colors for enabled and disabled states.